# Should rspec assigns work for a POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, post, rspec, controller

I am writing rspec tests for my Rails 4.2.5 controllers using rspec 3.4. I have a controller method that is creating  @position and then rendering a thank you page which uses data from @position.  The web pages all seem to render correctly but my rspec test is failing because it does not seem to recognize the @position object has been passed to the thank you page.

The controller method is:

```
def create_application
  application = Application.new application_params
  application.save
  @position = application.position
  render "thank_you"
end
```

The rspec example is:

```
it "renders the Thank You page for a successful application." do
  position = create :position
  application = build :application, position: position
  post :create_application, application: application.attributes
  expect(response).to render_template("thank_you")
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  expect(assigns(:position)).to eq(position)
end
```

The results I'm consistently seeing are:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:position)).to eq(position)

   expected: #<Position id: 422, title: "Position Title", description: "This is a description of the position", status: "open", company_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-02 16:47:19", updated_at: "2016-06-02 16:47:19">
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
```

So it appears rspec is not recognizing the @positiion variable as being set.  However, the thank you page uses properties of the @position object and when I manually test the page those properties are displayed correctly.

I have other, similar specs for GET requests and they all seem to work without any problems.  Is assigns supposed to work with POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  Since the form used to submit the data to the controller was not using the standard Rails REST pattern, it was submitting each field as a request parameter. In other words the controller action was receiving each field individually rather than as an object property.  This worked fine with the web pages because they were coded correctly.  However the rspec example was sending the parameters as part of the application object.

I changed this line of the rspec example:

```
post :create_application, application: application.attributes
```

to:

```
post :create_application, application.attributes
```

and now everything is working.